# Using angular ng-options in select but the array is changing in scope and it is being displayed later

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using select and loading values using ng-options

`<select class="label-filter" ng-model="filter" ng-init="filter=(labels[0].val)" ng-change="regCtrl.labelSelected()" ng-options="option.val as option.name for option in labels">`

I am changing $scope.labels array in controller file. But change is not getting visible instantly. After the button which calls that function is clicked twice or thrice then the new options appear in select menu

The function where i am changing

```
   this.containsObject = function(obj, list) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i]['name'] == obj['name']) {
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
 }    

this.addLabelsToFilter = function() {
    var labelList = [];
    labelList.push({'name':'All','val':''});
        for (var i = 0; i < self._annos.length; i++) {
            var entry = {};
            entry['name'] = self._annos[i]['label'];
            entry['val'] = self._annos[i]['label'];
            if(!self.containsObject(entry,labelList))
            labelList.push(entry);
    }

    $scope.labels = labelList;
}
```

This addLabelsToFIlter is being called in a function from model side

```
   this.loadCanvasImage = function(image){        
self._img.onload = function(){
        self._refresh(0, 0, false,self._curr_filter_label);

        self.addLabelsToFilter();
        console.log($scope.labels);
        self.setZoom();}}
```

Comment: Could you add the code there your controler changes the labels ?

Comment: Everytime the button is clicked the function is called and which then calls addLabelsToFIlter. But when i click the button two or three times then the changes appear

Comment: Try to modify your code to just work with `$scope.labels`, without using `labelList` and without destroying the initial reference of `$scope.labels`. You are always creating a new reference to your list of labels with `labelList` and that is why changes don't appear right away (they shouldn't appear at all unless there is some other code that is watching the `$scope.labels`).

Comment: I am declaring $scope.labels = `[{name:"All",val:""}] ;` and in the function `addLabelsToFilter` not creating empty list everytime. But the changes are reflected after 2 clicks instead of one

Comment: Still not coming on one click.

Comment: Instead of containing labels as listOfObjects taking it as list Of string it still requires min 2 or 3 clicks to reflect